# ID3 tagging software with grammar-aware title casing algorithm

Tags: windows, mp3, algorithms, filenames

Almost every piece of ID3 tagging software includes "dumb" title casing functionality ("title of the song iii" becomes "Title Of The Song Iii" rather than "Title of the Song III"); to produce a perfectly cased library, though, much of the work must be done by hand. Yes, there are programs with regular expression support which simplify the task, but regular expressions can't infer context, which is [everything](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Style/Language/English) when it comes to proper title casing.

Though the MusicBrainz folks have [a good system](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Style/Language/English) going, I don't agree with all their choices, and I don't want to replace all my existing tags with theirs, which aren't as complete as I'd like. With that in mind, has anyone yet written a program with a (preferably configurable) grammar-aware title casing algorithm that will, with the click of a button, automatically and properly case my entire library?

**Note**: I currently use 'dumb' casing, then naively replacing all the of and the and a and so on to small case. It gets you most of the way there, but still requires going over each and every new file by hand for edge cases, which is the portion of the workflow I'm trying to eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

On one hand you don't want to use MusicBrainz naming which has in most cases been entered and checked by real humans, instead you want to use an automated completely computer based system but it must not be dumb. Unfortunately, all computer algorithms are essentially dumb, just some give the impression of being less dumb than others.

But I may be able to offer a middle way, [Jaikoz Music Tagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz) displays your music in an essentially spreadsheet like view and allows you to automatically and update your songs from MusicBrainz. However, it also provides local editing controls including  a **Capitalizer** that lets you specify title case and sentence case together with a configurable list of words that should (not)be capitalized/lowercased. The capitalizer is also clever enough to recognize some special cases such as Mc and act as expected.

[image: Capitalizer Configuration]

You can easily apply Capitaliser to all/some fields and you can split the view between **BEFORE**  and **AFTER** to compare the auto edits so you can revert ones you don't like before saving.

[image: Jaikoz Audio Tagger UI]

Disclaimer: **I am the Jaikoz developer**